# Checking one variable against multiple values?

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

Currently, I'm doing something like this:

```php
if ( in_array ( $variable, ["a","b","c"] ) ) { ... }
```

Which reads a little easier than

```
if ( $variable == "a" || $variable == "b" || $variable == "c" ) { ... }
```

But I was wondering, are there more efficient ways, instead of checking a value in an array?

Comment: I like this way of doing things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
$my_array = array_flip(array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', ...));
if (isset($my_array[$variable])) ...
```

This has one-time O(n) cost to create $my_array, then checking for a match is O(1).

Comment: @GautamD3164 Nice implementation but might be slower than using in_array. And benchmarks are tests to see how well your code performs.

Comment: Ok @Remi-X but many of them suggetsed me that this is much faster and acurate one than in_array and you can see the ordertime will be better

Comment: How would it be more accurate? And where did you read/hear it's faster?

Comment: This approach is actually worse than `in_array()`, because of `array_flip()`. If you're concerned with performance, at least add `static $my_array; if(!isset($my_array)) ` before the first line. This way it only happens once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **switch case** statement for checking variable against multiple values.

Please refer the code snippet mentioned below

e.g.

```
  switch($a)
  {
      case 'a':
    //do something
      break;
     case 'b':
     //do something
     break; 
    case 'c':
    //do something
    break;
  }
```

Comment: I was trying to make it shorter :P Also, I was planning to use it on a `?:` condition.